# Replace missing values in a vector with the last value that was not missing in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I am trying to import a table from a web page using the readHtmlTable function, this is the first few rows of what the data looks like when it is in R.

```
              Event                Athlete Country      Result  Medal year
1          100m Men              Tom Burke     USA        12.0   GOLD 1896
2                            Fritz Hofmann     DEU   12.2 est. SILVER 1896
3                             Francis Lane     USA        12.6 BRONZE 1896
4                          Alajos Szokolyi     HUN   12.6 est. BRONZE 1896
5          400m Men              Tom Burke     USA        54.2   GOLD 1896
6                          Herbert Jamison     USA         n/a SILVER 1896
7                           Charles Gmelin     GBR         n/a BRONZE 1896
8          800m Men            Teddy Flack     AUS      2:11.0   GOLD 1896
9                            Nֳ¡ndor Dֳ¡ni     HUN 2:11.8 est. SILVER 1896
10                       Demitrios Golemis     GRE         n/a BRONZE 1896
```

Now if you look at the event column you can see some of the rows of the event field empty, this is the way the table is on the website, what I am looking for is the most efficient way to fill those blanks so at the end it should look like this

```
              Event       Athlete      Country      Result  Medal year
1          100m Men       Tom Burke       USA        12.0   GOLD 1896
2          100m Men       Fritz Hofmann   DEU   12.2 est. SILVER 1896
3          100m Men       Francis Lane    USA        12.6 BRONZE 1896
4          100m Men       Alajos Szokolyi HUN   12.6 est. BRONZE 1896
5          400m Men       Tom Burke       USA        54.2   GOLD 1896
```

Basically every time a field in the Event column is empty I need to fill it with the last value that was not empty. The column is saved in R as a factor and I know that technically I can do this using a for loop and going over all of the vector elements but this is very time consuming considering the fat that there are about 300000 rows in this table. I am hoping for something more efficient

Comment: Fill the empty fields with NA and then use `na.locf` from the zoo package.  See `library(zoo); ?na.locf`for help  and google for `na.locf` to find many additional examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a toy example of how the [purrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html) package could be used to solve your problem, assuming the data is in a `data.frame` and the missing values are `NA`:

```
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame("event" = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, 5), "other" = 1:7)

df
#     event other
# 1     1     1
# 2    NA     2
# 3     2     3
# 4    NA     4
# 5     3     5
# 6    NA     6
# 7     5     7


df$event <- accumulate(.x = df$event, .f = function(x, y) { if(is.na(y)) x else y })

df
#     event other
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     3
# 4     2     4
# 5     3     5
# 6     3     6
# 7     5     7
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fill` function from the R Studio package `tidyr` is designed to do this kind of data cleaning.  We'll use it with `mutate` from the `dplyr` package which will first replace missing values with `NA`.  Your data is in data frame `df` Code looks like

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_fill <- df %>% mutate(Event = ifelse(Event == "", NA,Event)) %>%
                  fill(Event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method using `rle` and `inverse.rle`:

```
# create run length encoding
temp <- rle(df$event)
# fill in missing values with previous values
temp$values[is.na(temp$values)] <- temp$values[which(is.na(temp$values))-1]

# fill in vector of data.frame
df$event <- inverse.rle(temp)
```

Note that this won't work if there is a missing value in the first position of the variable.